# how to drop_caches in OpenVZ centos6 container

Tags: centos, memory, virtual-machines, openvz, proxmox

I have tried

```
sudo sh -c 'echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches'

sudo echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches

echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches

echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

and a bunch of other variations but with every try I get

```
bash: /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches: Permission denied
```

How do I clear the ram used for buffers/cache in my centos6 openvz container?

It seems like the only way to do what I need is to reboot the container.

Comment: Why would you want to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get a real non-OpenVZ machine (KVM, Xen, etc) and this will work just fine. With OpenVZ, you don't get your own kernel instance and as such, are restricted from performing commands like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

Comment: That was one of the things I also tried and it doesn't work